# Bootstrap Vue and Axios

Tags: html, ajax, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue

Trying to get the HTML from this Axios call to render inside the b-tabs. No luck. It works everywhere but there. Still very new to Vue, and a little stumped as to what I'm missing here. I feel like maybe compile is useful here, but may be overshooting as well.

The HTML:

```
<div id="tabby">
 
    <b-tabs>
      <b-tab title="Atari 2600" active>
        

 <div id="app">  
                <div v-html="results"></div>
            </div>

        <b-spinner id="loader1" style="display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:200px;">
    
        

      </b-tab>

       <b-tab title="3DS">
        
         <div id="app2">  
                <div v-html="results"></div>
            </div>

        <b-spinner id="loader2" style="display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:200px;">
    
        

      </b-tab>


    </b-tabs>

</div>
```

The Vue:

```
const url = "someurl";

const vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            
          results: ''
        
        },
        mounted() {
          axios.get(url, {params: { section: 'atari2600'}}).then(response => {
            this.results = response.data
            console.log(response);
            $('#loader1').hide();
          })
        }
      });


const vm2 = new Vue({
        el: '#app2',
        data: {
            
          results: ''
        
        },
        mounted() {
          axios.get(url, {params: { section: '3ds'}}).then(response => {
            this.results = response.data
            console.log(response);
            $('#loader2').hide();
          })
        }
      });

 const vms = new Vue({ el: '#tabby' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I was rendering the tabs separately, which was breaking everything.

```
const vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            
          results: ''
        
        },
        el: '#tabby',
        mounted() {
          axios.get(url, {params: { section: 'atari2600'}}).then(response => {
            this.results = response.data
            console.log(response);
            $('#loader1').hide();
          })
        }
      });
```